Get data via SQL with connection string doesn't work
I want to create an Excel file that can fetch data from SQL. This should be with embedded username & password so I can pass on the file to a colleague who doesn't have SQL permissions. I have made sure the SQL users for this is readonly, for damage control.
I am using the legacy Microsoft Query to get data, where I can choose to enable "save password" in the conn string.

But when I pass it on to my colleague, he gets an error since it still tries to use his user account to run the SQL syntax.

Any ideas of what I'm missing here?
Tried adding "PWD=[password]" to the connection string, and also Authentication settings -> Choose "none" option, which means log on to data source should use the connection string.

You combine trustedconnection AND user/password in the first screenshot which isn't correct already. Remove the trustedconnection thing. Also, i don't know excel, but i'm pretty sure you might as well give this user your login, because he will have it and you might end up in trouble. Better ask your dba to give him proper login

Thanks for the tip. Turns out the UID user was not set up properly for SQL access, so after that was corrected by IT, it works.
